# Encountered strange situation with references as function parameter

Tags: c++

There is this method: `SCardListReaders`, having such parameters:

```
LONG WINAPI SCardListReaders(
  _In_      SCARDCONTEXT hContext,
  _In_opt_  LPCTSTR mszGroups,
  _Out_     LPTSTR mszReaders,
  _Inout_   LPDWORD pcchReaders
);
```

And being called like this(from MSDN):

```
LPTSTR          pmszReaders = NULL;
LPTSTR          pReader;
LONG            lReturn, lReturn2;
DWORD           cch = SCARD_AUTOALLOCATE;

// Retrieve the list the readers.
// hSC was set by a previous call to SCardEstablishContext.
lReturn = SCardListReaders(hSC,
                           NULL,
                           (LPTSTR)&pmszReaders,
                           &cch );
...
```

I am confused by the `pmszReaders` variable. Particularly, for Unicode builds it is already `WCHAR*` to my understanding, so why is `&pmszReaders` passed to the `ScardListReaders` function above, why not directly `pmszReaders`? (it is already a pointer right?).

Comment: You should tag your question with `winapi`, you will probably attract more people and assist those who know nothing about `winapi` in avoiding questions they have no expertise in answering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, you pass a pointer to a pre-allocated buffer (a `LPTSTR`). And that's why `mszReaders` is declared as `LPTSTR`.

But note that `SCARD_AUTOALLOCATE` is passed as last parameter. Only in this case, `mszReaders` is interpreted as pointer to pointer.

From MSDN:

pcchReaders [in, out]

Length of the mszReaders buffer in characters. This parameter receives the actual length of the multi-string structure, including all trailing null characters. If the buffer length is specified as SCARD_AUTOALLOCATE, then mszReaders is converted to a pointer to a byte pointer, and receives the address of a block of memory containing the multi-string structure. This block of memory must be deallocated with SCardFreeMemory.

Comment: this seems to be best explanation. although it says "mszReaders is converted to a pointer to a byte pointer" but what would happen if in such a case, user just submitted LPTSTR, probably it wouldn't work ..

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit obtuse to use `(LPTSTR)&pmszReaders` but according to the function documentation you'll see taht pmszReaders is a `Multi-string`.
They are giving you an array of `LPTSTR` by mallocing memory to the `LPTSTR` pointer you passed in.

The reasoning behind using `LPTSTR` instead of `LPTSTR*` is that Microsoft API's don't like using `*` in their API functions hence LPTSTR's existence in the first place.

To clarify, the `LPTSTR`you are returned is in the format:

```
name1\0name2\0name3\0
```

Making it an `LPTSTR` and not an `LPTSTR*`.

You can safely ignore the `_in_ _Out_` parts of code, they are for Microsoft profiling and general helpfulness. They don't have any effect on compiled code.

Comment: Hi Serdalis, what I am confused is that function signature says it wants `_Out_ LPTSTR mszReaders` parameter. Meaning we should pass it a variable of type `LPTSTR` right? The code I posted passes some kind of double pointer right? e.g., `&pmszReaders` - which is not type of `LPTSTR`. Do you see what I mean?

Comment: Yes you are passing a pointer to a pointer to memory. This allows the function to assign memory to the pointer you passed in so it can populate it's list of char arrays. The reasoning behind using `LPTSTR` is a stylistic choice by Microsoft.

Comment: Yes but that is what confused me. It seems it is passing a pointer to pointer, BUT, the function signature said it wanted an `LPTSTR` type, and NOT a pointer to pointer - you see what I mean?

Comment: It is confusing, and the documentation doesn't make it very clear but it is required if you are receiving an arbitrary length array from the function. If you pass in a `>0 pcchReaders` value and an array of the same size you can get away with passing in just a normal `LPTSTR` instead of a reference.

Comment: if I fon't use SCARD_AUTOALOCATE in pcchReaders that is indeed a bit different story. But you see what confused me? The function said it wanted `LPTSTR` as a parameter, but actually a pointer to pointer was passed to it ..

Answer (score 0):

From MSDN :

> ```
> mszReaders [out]
>
>     Multi-string that lists the card readers within the supplied reader groups. 
>     If this value is NULL, SCardListReaders ignores the buffer length supplied 
>     in pcchReaders, writes the length of the buffer that would have been 
>     returned if this parameter had not been NULL to pcchReaders, 
>     and returns a success code.
> ```

It's a multi-string - as an array of string - so you need to take the address of the first reader as a parameter (pmszReaders being a `WCHAR*`, in others words a "`wstring`" ).

Comment: what I am confused is that function signature says it wants `_Out_     LPTSTR mszReaders` parameter. Meaning we should pass it a variable of type `LPTSTR` right? The code I posted passes some kind of double pointer right? e.g., `&pmszReaders` - which is not type of `LPTSTR`. did you get what I mean?

Comment: ah okay. It's as Serdalis said, it's an aesthetic choice : a pointer to memory (e.g. int* p = 0xdeadbeef) is also a value ( 0xdeadbeef in the example) therefore you can drop the star. It's more "pretty" (beauty is in the eye of the beholder) but a bit more ambiguous.

Comment: Hey gerorgesl, please see my last comment to Serdalis